# Sequelize ORDER BY ASC numeric string

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

please help in this matter. So my scenario is that I have driver app (flutter) that fetch ongoing orders that needed to be delivered. I would like to fetch orders according to `order` column ASC, I already set that in my backend. Here is the code:

```
  static async getOngoingOrders(driverId, cb) {
     try {
       const orders = {
       instant: [],
       scheduled: [],
     };

     // @scheduled
     if (!orders.instant.length) {
      const scheduledOrders = await BatchOrder.findAll({
        where: {
         deliveryDate: {
          [Op.gte]: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
          [Op.lt]: moment().add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        },
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: BatchSchedule,
          attributes: ["id", "name", "start", "end"],
        },
        {
          model: BatchDriver,
          where: {
            DriverId: driverId,
            status: "Driver on the Way",
          },
          attributes: ["status", "DriverId"],
          include: [
            {
              model: Order,
              where: {
                status: {
                  [Op.not]: ["Not Delivered", "Complained"],
                },
              },
              attributes: ["id", "orderId", "status", "order"],
              include: [
                {
                  model: User,
                  attributes: ["fullName", "phoneNumber", "uid"],
                },
                {
                  model: Address,
                  attributes: [
                    "name",
                    "address",
                    "details",
                    "notes",
                    "longitude",
                    "latitude",
                  ],
                },
              ],
              // ******* here is the ASC *******
              order: [["order", "ASC"]],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      attributes: ["id", "deliveryDate"],
    });

    const formattedScheduledOrder = scheduledOrders.map((batch) => {
      const formattedOrder = {
        name: batch.BatchSchedule.name,
        start: batch.BatchSchedule.start.substr(0, 5),
        end: batch.BatchSchedule.end.substr(0, 5),
        Orders: [],
      };

      let delivered = 0;

      batch.BatchDrivers[0].Orders.map((order) => {
        if (
          order.status === "Delivered"
        ) {
          delivered++;
        } else {
          formattedOrder.Orders.push({
            id: order.id,
            order: order.order,
            orderId: order.orderId,
            fullName: order.User.fullName,
            phoneNumber: order.User.phoneNumber,
            firestoreId: order.User.uid,
            Address: {
              name: order.Address.name,
              address: order.Address.address,
              details: order.Address.details,
              notes: order.Address.notes,
              longitude: order.Address.longitude,
              latitude: order.Address.latitude,
            },
          });
        }
      });

      formattedOrder.delivered = `${delivered}/${batch.BatchDrivers[0].Orders.length}`;

      return formattedOrder;
    });

    orders.scheduled = formattedScheduledOrder;
    // ***** tried add this, but got another problem, explanation below *****
    // orders.scheduled.map((v) =>
    //   v.Orders.length > 1
    //     ? v.Orders.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
    //     : v.Orders
    // );
    // console.log(orders.scheduled);
  }

  cb(null, orders);
} catch (err) {
  cb(err, null);
}
}
```

Here what I got in Insomnia/Postman

[image]

As above image, it doesn't effected by `order: [["order", "ASC"]]`.

I also have tried to change `order: [[Sequelize.literal("Orders.order"), "ASC"]]`.

I also have tried to add map loop as mentioned in above commented code. With that loop I got what I wanted/expected, but I receive another problem. The problem is that in driver app there is a button to change the status (PATCH) of order to `delivered/not delivered`, when That button is clicked I will get

```
// in ongoing orders
{
 instant: [],
 scheduled: []
}
```

Please let me know if there are any more info needed, Thanks :)

**EDITED**

Screenshot of query when fetch on going orders from driver side

[image]

Screenshot of fetch orders from user side (INSOMNIA/POSTMAN)

[image]

Screenshot of Orders table

[image]

**EDITED (2)**

Screenshot of query after adding `separate: true`

[image]

Screenshot fetch ongoing orders after adding `separate: true`

[image]

I added `separate: true` like below:

```
include: [
 {
  model: Order,
  *** here ***
  separate: true,
  where: ....
 }
]
```

Comment: Did you try to indicate `separate: true` in `Order` include? At least it could help to sort alphabetically.

Comment: @Anatoly Yes I've tried to add `separate: true`, I received empty array `Orders: []` when I fetch ongoing orders

Comment: Can you check what SQL queries were generated for orders?

Comment: @Anatoly I'm sorry, I didn't get what you mean. I've added extra information, hopefully that's what you meant

Comment: I see that order fetched along with BatchDrivers so you propably misplaced `separate` option. Can you update the Sequelize query in the post with `separate` option?

Comment: @Anatoly I updated the post & added separate option, let me know if more info needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Until now I didn't find the solution, So I did sort using js sort built function